# Spark explode array of string to columns

Tags: java, arrays, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark with Java and I have a dataframe like this:

```
id  | array_column
-------------------
12  | [a:123, b:125, c:456]
13  | [a:443, b:225, c:126]
```

I want to explode `array_column` with the same id, however `explode` doesn't work, because I want dataframe to become:

```
id  | a  | b  | c
-------------------
12  |123 |125 | 456 
13  |443 |225 | 126
```

Comment: Do you have fixed amount of elements in map or it can be changed?

Comment: @ArtemAstashov The number is not fixed but it can be blocked with a large number if needed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following approach will work on variable length lists in `array_column`. The approach uses `explode` to expand the list of string elements in `array_column` before splitting each string element using `:` into two different columns `col_name` and `col_val` respectively. Finally a pivot is used with a group by to transpose the data into the desired format.

The following example uses the pyspark api but can easily be translated to the java/scala apis as they are similar. I assumed your dataset is in a dataframe named `input_df`

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

output_df = (
    input_df.select("id",F.explode("array_column").alias("acol"))
            .select(
                "id",
                F.split("acol",":")[0].alias("col_name"),
                F.split("acol",":")[1].cast("integer").alias("col_val")
            )
            .groupBy("id")
            .pivot("col_name")
            .max("col_val")
)
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 5):

A very similar approach like ggordon's answer in Java:

```java
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.*;

Dataset<Row> df = ...

df.withColumn("array_column", explode(col("array_column")))
        .withColumn("array_column", split(col("array_column"), ":"))
        .withColumn("key", col("array_column").getItem(0))
        .withColumn("value", col("array_column").getItem(1))
        .groupBy(col("id"))
        .pivot(col("key"))
        .agg(first("value")) //1
        .show();
```

Output:

```
+---+---+---+---+
| id|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+---+
| 12|456|225|126|
| 11|123|125|456|
+---+---+---+---+
```

I assume that the combination of `id` and and the key field in the array is unique. That's why the aggregation function used at `//1` is `first`. If this combination is not unique, the aggregation function could be changed to `collect_list` in order to get an array of all matching values.

Answer (score 1):

Extracting column names from strings inside columns:

- create a proper JSON string (with quote symbols around json objects and values)
- create schema using this column
- create struct and explode it into columns

Input example:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(12, ['a:123', 'b:125', 'c:456']),
     (13, ['a:443', 'b:225', 'c:126'])],
    ['id', 'array_col'])

df.show(truncate=0)
# +---+---------------------+
# |id |array_col            |
# +---+---------------------+
# |12 |[a:123, b:125, c:456]|
# |13 |[a:443, b:225, c:126]|
# +---+---------------------+
```

Script:

```py
df = df.withColumn("array_col", F.expr("to_json(str_to_map(array_join(array_col, ',')))"))
json_schema = spark.read.json(df.rdd.map(lambda row: row.array_col)).schema
df = df.withColumn("array_col", F.from_json("array_col", json_schema))
df = df.select("*", "array_col.*").drop("array_col")

df.show()
# +---+---+---+---+
# | id|  a|  b|  c|
# +---+---+---+---+
# | 12|123|125|456|
# | 13|443|225|126|
# +---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: very clever trick with converting to JSON and rebuilding dataframe from schema. ++ for that.